# iOS FirebaseCrashlytics upload_symbols and run scripts are not inside FirebaseCrashlytics.framework

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm migrating Fabric.framework & Crashlytics to use FirebaseCrashlytics, following

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk

But I cannot see either `run` or `upload-symbols`.
So I cannot setup this

```
/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
```

I'm using Carthage and the FirebaseCrashlytics.framework just contains:

[image]

If I download the zip manually (the one that Carthage uses) they are one level app.

[image]

If I create the project with cocoapods
[image]

Any help on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found that Carthage + FirebaseCrashlytics are not supporting this automatically.
We have to download manually.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5074